# Populating @Html.DropDownListFor -- OK from hard-coded values, error from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, list, asp.net-mvc-4

We are populating drop down lists on our forms, built in C# ASP.NET MVC 4 (sometimes 5).  Thanks to SOF, I built a temporary list like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Generate a list of countries.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>List(SelectListItem)</returns>
/// <remarks>Values are from ISO 3166-1 alpha-3</remarks>
public static List<SelectListItem> Countries()
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "United States of America", Value = "USA", Selected = true });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Australia", Value = "AUS" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Canada", Value = "CAN" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mexico", Value = "MEX" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "United Kingdom", Value = "GBR" });

    return items;
}
```

Then passed this into the ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.CountryList = SelectLists.Countries();
```

and rendered it as:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( model=>model.country_code, 
    (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CountryList )
```

This part all worked just fine.

Now the team is implementing code to retrieve the lookups from the database instead of from mock data, and things are not fine.  Our business object method accepts a lookup type, in this case "Country", and should return a `List<SelectListItem>`:

Controller:

```
List<SelectListItem> countryList = GetLookupData( "Country" );
ViewBag.CountryList = countryList;
```

Model:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetLookupData(string lookupType)
{
    MPPEntities dbContext = new MPPEntities();
    var query = (from c in dbContext.SystemLookups
                    where c.lookup_type == lookupType
                    orderby c.order_by
                    select new SelectListItem { Text = c.name, Value = c.value })
                    .ToList<SelectListItem>();

    return (List<SelectListItem>)query;
}
```

While we are debugging the LINQ, `query` contains the correct data.  But when the debugger returns to the controller, `countryList` fails as "Could not evaluate expression."  And then of course the view itself fails.

Based on the observation that the mock list worked and that the real list contains the correct data, I deduce that the point of failure is in the conversion from a generic collection to `List<SelectListItem>`.  What is the right way to convert the list type?

ETA: The error in the CSHTML file is:
"RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException was unhandled by user code."  And this is with the fewer casts as recommended below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to make many useless castings...

Could you try

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetLookupData(string lookupType)
    {
       MPPEntities dbContext = new MPPEntities();
       return (from c in dbContext.SystemLookups
                    where c.lookup_type == lookupType
                    orderby c.order_by
                    select new SelectListItem { Text = c.name, Value = c.value })
                    .ToList();
    }
```

Could you try, in your view

```
@{
  var contryCodes = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CountryList;
}

@Html.DropDownListFor( model=>model.country_code, 
    countryCodes )
```

cause it looks like a problem with dynamic (ViewBag)...

Comment: Nope, I got the same `RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException` as before.

Comment: Didn't work. The cast to the view variable raises the exception.

Comment: I'm certain the problem is not in the view, as the view rendered properly when I passed my mocked list in the ViewBag.  The problem has to be that what I want to put into the bag, is not what I'm actually putting into the bag.

Comment: And now, a month later, this approach works PERFECTLY.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer always be patient ;)

Comment: FSM grant me patience RIGHT NOW!  Srsly, though, last month the same code had been raising exceptions in the view, and now it works.  Something must have accidentally gotten fixed.